# FileNotFoundException Permission Denied Error

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

I am writing an Excel file using Apache POI. The file is to be written in /opt/lampp/htdocs/{projectName}/{taskFolder}. This is my code...

```
    String xlsxOutput = taskFolder + File.separator + "results_pe.xlsx";

    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Phrase Extraction");
    XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);

    Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
    cell.setCellValue("Task: " + taskName + "_" + taskCreationTime);

    row = sheet.createRow(1);
    cell = row.createCell(0);
    cell.setCellValue("Phrase: " + phrase);
    -----------------
    -----------------

    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(xlsxOutput);
    wb.write(fileOutputStream);

    fileOutputStream.close();
```

I get the error at the following point:

```
     FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(xlsxOutput);
```

I have tried chmod -R 777 for the folder. Doesn't work. I tried chown to my login and group and even root. Still doesn't work. I am at wits end. Help would  be appreciated.

Comment: check the permissions on the parent folders... they may not be open.

Comment: tried chmod 777 for the project name folder...should I try for the entire htdocs folder?

Comment: yeah, i would check that too.

Comment: @ChrisBolton ... that doesn't work either.

Comment: what is the value of xlsxOutput?

Comment: Gives me the taskname and phrase